# How to make a spectrum plot

Tags: python, spectrum

I am trying to replicate a spectrum plot like the figure below with both Python and Matlab, no success so far.

[image]

The image is from [Electric Field Instrument](https://themis.igpp.ucla.edu/dfb_caveats.shtml) data. The plot should have time on x-axis, frequency on y-axis and colorbar on the right y-axis.

The data is a two dimensional matrix, each row represents the time stamp, the column represents different frequency after FFT. the problem is the data has a lot of NaN values, only a few frequency has data, when I used `plt.imshow()` it give me completely blank image. Besides, the value ranges from `1e-12 to 1e-7`, very small.

Any hint on how to visualize image like this would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of the data. The data is from NASA EFI data.
[image]

I utilized `plt.imshow` with Python and `imagesc` in Matlab with the whole 2d matrix, it give me blank image of the same color.
Below is my Python code trial, all gave me wrong images:

```
plt.matshow(dt, cmap='jet');plt.colorbar(); plt.show()
```

[image]

```
for i in range(dt.shape[0]):
      plt.plot(dt.iloc[i, :]);plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data. If you want help figuring out why your code didn't work, please also show your code as a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `imshow` because this will display it as if it were an image (because you have a 2D matrix).

You need to plot each row separately, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sin1 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100))
sin2 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)) + 0.5
sin3 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)) + 1

sin1[10] = np.nan
sin2[20] = np.nan
sin3[30] = np.nan

data = np.array([sin1, sin2, sin3])

# plot each row as a separate series
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(data[i, :])

plt.show()
```

and then the nan's should just be empty spots in the graph.

[image: plot]